# Toggle class on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below unordered list

```
<ul>
<li class="item">Link 1</li>
<li class="item">link 2</li>
<li class="item">Link 3</li>
</ul>
```

I am currently using the following javascript to toggle the class `"open"` to any `<li>` element with the "item" class referenced.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.item').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
      });
    });
```

I would like to make it so that the class `"open"` can only be applied to one `"item"` element at a time.

Therefore for example: If the user clicks `"Link 2"` after having already clicked `"Link 1"`. `"Link 1"` would lose the `"open"` class and the `"open"` class would be attributed to "Link 2".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way in your jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.item').click(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('open');
     $(this).siblings().removeClass('open');
   });
 });
```

This basically attributes the `open` class to the item you're clicking while simultaneously removing it from any `siblings` that have the same class.

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/pnortmrL/

Comment: If this solved the issue, please mark as the answer.